# Trying to access JAR FILE inside $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\$(Release.PrimaryArtifactSourceAlias)

Tags: linux, bash, unix, azure-devops

Trying to access jar file inside the path sudo chmod 777 $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)$(Release.PrimaryArtifactSourceAlias)/**.jar in linux bash file
While passing the command as inline in Azure it worked perfectly fine but while accessing it as file

```
 sudo chmod 777 $SYSTEM_DEFAULTWORKINGDIRECTORY/\$RELEASE_PRIMARAYARTIFACTSOURCEALIAS)\/**.jar
```

But ** is not accessible ?
What is the Right syntax to access the jar in azure DeVops bash file

Comment: ls -la command is also not working in the bash script file but the same was working when I'm giving it in inline command in Azure devops bash task

Comment: `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)$(Release.PrimaryArtifactSourceAlias)` looks weird, to say the least. If this is supposed to be part of a bash script, I would need to see the whole line where this expression occurs.

Comment: Don't post relevant code in a comment. Update your question with it. I don't see a `sudo` in your question. And format code as `code` in your question.

Comment: please recheck my question

Answer (score 0):

Your command contains an unbalanced parenthese (closing parenhese, but no corresponding open one).

By using a `\` in front of `$RELEASE_PRIMARAYARTIFACTSOURCEALIAS`, you instruct the shell to **not** substitute the variable.

`**` is not a valid bash glob character, unless you explicitly turn on this feature:

```
shopt -s globstar
```

Comment: I'm new to bash script and not aware of shopt -s globstar .
Can you please elaborate how to enable it in azure devops bash task .

Comment: I don't know azure. What I would do (it should be possible in azure as well) to start a bash script, and inside this script, you can do whatever you want - including setting the _globstar_ option. This also makes debugging easier, because you decouple your bash task from embedding it into azure. Another possibility would be to use zsh instead of bash, which has `**` enabled by default.